# How do I filter across Tableau workbooks through the dropdowns?

Tags: javascript, api, filter, tableau-api

Please be patient with my English, and it's my first time to be here. I am very new to Tableau and JavaScript as well. I am trying to find a way to filter the dashboards in a different place. For example, when I click a person name from a list on the first dashboard and it shows a result, once I click another dashboard from the drop-down (not on API, just come from an HTML nav bar), this dashboard should show any results with the person name I chose on the first dashboard.

Like this: I'm viewing Dashboard 1. I apply filter Anthony. Then I go to Dashboard 2 after clicking this on drop-down. IF Dashboard 2 also has a filter named exactly "Anthony" show the result automatically.

I tried to research about this, but it does not help very much. I read the API reference and I thought getFilterAsync() from FilterEvent Class would work, but it doesn't. I would appreciate if you can explain or show an example with Javascript codes constructively. [This example](https://www.interworks.com/blog/tladd/2013/10/24/truly-global-filtering-across-multiple-tableau-workbooks-javascript-api) is similar to my goal, but I don't plan to use two dashboards and textbox/button on the same page. [Another example](http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/samples/en-us/js_api/tutorial.htm) is sort of what I want, but I don't need to put specific values on method to filter. I need to filter across workbooks after clicking anything on the API. It's not just a person name. It can be a date, number, location, etc. I want to know how I make filter values/parameters active on any dashboards.

Any response will be helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

use action filter, where you specify the source dashboard and then the target dashboard

Comment: OP is clearly asking in reference to JSAPI and not Tableau Desktop.

Comment: Pirate X is right. I don't want anything with tableau desktop. I need to know how to do this with JSAPI.